# Completely remove the default option _none in select list

Tags: forms, hooks

This question has been asked many times but I can't find the complete solution. I want to remove the default option from a select `value="_none"`.

```
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-type-expert" id="edit-field-type-expert" name="field_type_expert" class="form-select valid" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="_none">- Aucun(e) -</option>
    <option value="3">Entité</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Membre</option>
</select>
```

I can do a `hook_form_alter`:

```
$form['field_type_expert']['widget']['#options']['_none'] = '';
```

possibly if necessary

```
unset($form['field_type_expert']['widget']['#options']['_none']);
```

It partially works. We always see the empty option in the select. It's an aesthetic detail but is it possible to find a solution?

Here is the result on Chrome / MacOS

[image]

Comment: Is the field required?

Comment: @Kevin Yes and I noticed that this could cause a problem with my various attempts.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but in some cases the form could no longer be validated.

Comment: IIRC if you set field as required none option wot be displayed in dropdown.

Comment: IIRC setting as required _and_ setting a default value should hide the `_none` option

Comment: So simple. Thanks. Post your answer and I'll mark it as correct.